# Populate document with other fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I got the following document:

```
{
  "_id": "5b5df332879b4769739e3ed0",
  "name": "Back workout",
  "exercises": [{
    "_id": "5b5df9a7879b4769739e3ed1",
    "results": [{"reps":"10","weight":"85"}, {"reps":"8","weight":"70"}]
  }]
}
```

I want to populate the exercise based on the `_id` and also append the `results` data.

Expected output:

```
{
  "_id": "5b5df332879b4769739e3ed0",
  "name": "Back workout",
  "exercises": [{
    "_id": "5b5df9a7879b4769739e3ed1",
    "name": "EXERCISE_NAME",
    "results": [{"reps":"10","weight":"85"}, {"reps":"8","weight":"70"}]
  }]
}
```

My Schema looks like this:

```
const WorkoutSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  exercises: [{
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise' },
    results: Array,
  }],
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
});
```

My query looks like this:

```
exports.listAll = async (request, h) => {
  const workoutCollection = await Workout
    .find()
    .populate('exercise');

  return { data: workoutCollection };
};
```

Comment: Can you post the current query you are using?

Comment: see the edit @Jack